# Date.Parse is Not working on existing code

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using Date. Parse (string date) for Converting String To Date. In this String I am using dates based on Logged in User Locale Format. But It's Not working on my existing apex code (API Version 34.0) but working on New code (API Version 37.0). When I Changed my Existing Code API version to 37.0 that time also not working. I am getting the invalid date error. And it's working in Execute Anonymous Window also.

---

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="TestController" docType="html-5.0" sidebar="false" id="pg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    var format ='{!dateFormat}';
    console.log(format);
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: format
    });
});


</script>
<apex:form id="frm">
<apex:pageBlock id="pgblk">
<input value="{!hiddenValue}" type="text" id="datepicker"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" value="Execute" />
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class TestController {

public Date dateVariable {get;set;}
public String dateFormat {get;set;}
public String hiddenValue {get;set;}

public TestController(){
    dateFormat = loggedin_user_locale_Date_Format__c.getValues(UserInfo.getLocale()).Date_Format__c;
    system.debug('Date Format--> '+dateFormat);
}

public PageReference doSomething(){
  hiddenValue=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('datepicker'); 
  system.debug('hiddenValue--> '+hiddenValue);
  dateVariable=Date.parse(hiddenValue);
  system.debug('dateVariable--> '+dateVariable);

  return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: You must [edit] your post to include some of the faulty inputs you have experienced if we are to be able to help.

Answer (score -2):

It constructs a Date from a String. The format of the String depends on the local date format.

```
Date myDate = Date.parse('12/27/2009');

System.debug('####'+myDate);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: His first sentence said that he's actually using the parse method !

Comment: Yeah you really only had to read the first five words to figure out *this is what the OP is already trying, and it's not working*.